# Get data from nested arrays two layers deep based on sub-index

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this json schema

```js
"header": {
        "self": {},
        "items": [
            {
                "_id": "5ec7e61979ec9914ecefc539",
                "title": "Test",
                "root": "true",
                "alignment": "left",
                "page": "test",
                "translate": "",
                "toggle": "",
                "icon": "",
                "IsActive": 1,
                "submenu": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5ece913a353a71309084768d",
                        "title": "Sub Test",
                        "bullet": "dot",
                        "page": "test",
                        "translate": "MENU.TEST1",
                        "icon": "flaticon-stes-3",
                        "IsActive": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ece935d79972f0390997179",
                        "title": "Sub Test",
                        "bullet": "dot",
                        "page": "test",
                        "translate": "MENU.TEST2",
                        "icon": "flaticon-stes-3",
                        "IsActive": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

```js
// Index based on a previous query
this.db.collection('AssetData').find({"header.items.$.submenu.[0]._id":ObjectID("5ece913a353a71309084768d"));

//Tried with elemMatch
this.db.collection('AssetData').find(
                                {
                                "header.items": {
                                    $elemMatch:{
                                        "submenu": {
                                            $elemMatch:{
                                            "_id":ObjectID("5ece913a353a71309084768d")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                               });
```

And I am wanting to retrieve one of the sub-menu object data based on the _id from the sub-menu, but I'm having trouble retrieving it.

I'm not sure If I could use an index of the second array from another query to obtain the data, or if there's another way that I'm missing like elem match.

I am using MongoDB 3.5.6.

What would be the best way to retrieve this?

Comment: What is the expected output here? Find returns the whole data on the match. Do you want only the matched submenu like `{
                        "_id": "5ece913a353a71309084768d",
                        "title": "Sub Test",
                        "bullet": "dot",
                        "page": "test",
                        "translate": "MENU.TEST1",
                        "icon": "flaticon-stes-3",
                        "IsActive": 1
                    }`

Comment: @palaѕн yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Index based on a previous query
this.db.collection('AssetData').find({"header.items.$.submenu.[0]._id":ObjectID("5ece913a353a71309084768d")});

//Tried with elemMatch
this.db.collection('AssetData').find(
                                {
                                "header.items": {
                                    $elemMatch:{
                                        "submenu": {
                                            $elemMatch:{
                                            "_id":ObjectID("5ece913a353a71309084768d")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                               }).exec(function(err, item) {
console.log(item);
// here you can retrieve the stock from item, as you wish
                               });
```

hopefully it will help you